# How to covert a const char* [] to a single block of memory, say char* ptr

Tags: c++

```
const char* colors[] = {"Red", "Blue", "Green"};
*ptr = new char[30];
memset(ptr,0,30);
```

I want to store colors(2-D) to ptr(1-D), something like this =>

```
ptr = "Red";
ptr+10 = "Blue";
ptr+20 = "Green";
```

this gives me lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Could someone guide me with this, please?

Comment: [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)

Comment: Why don't you use strings?

Comment: Have you researched any possible solutions? What did you find?

Comment: You could do `"Red\0Blue\0Green"` to get continuous memory containing those three strings, but this sounds like an XY problem. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: That's similar to writing `int x = 1; x + 2 = 4;`.

Comment: `std::ostringstream os; os << std::setw(10) << std::left << colors[0] << std::setw(10) << std::left << colors[1] << std::setw(10) << std::left << colors[2];`

Comment: Second line is very strange. May be is

    char *ptr = new char[30]; ?

Comment: `ptr = "Red";` You've just re-assigned the pointer so the mem you `new`d is lost.

Comment: Whoever taught you that `char *` was an appropriate type for text was lying to you. Use `std::string`, it behaves how you want it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you request that :

```
strcpy(ptr, "red");
strcpy(ptr+10, "Blue");
strcpy(ptr+20, "Green");
```

after it is your responsibility to know where you placed the strings

Can be more practical/generic to have only one null char between each and at least two null char after the last ?

But frankly there are more practical/safe solutions using std::vector ...

---

About the error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment", you have it for the lines

```
ptr+10 = "Blue";
ptr+20 = "Green";
```

`ptr+n` is not a *lvalue* but a value, typically it is not a variable

Comment: please add some more explaination. Providing only the code is a good recipe to grow cargo cult programmers. Eg why does OPs code not work?

Comment: Thanks!! it works!! I feel so silly asking this question :D Do you have any idea why I was getting that error with the way I was trying to do it?

Comment: @ShubhamSingla because you need to learn a little bit about C++ and built-in types and classes and...

Comment: ptr+10 = "Blue"; you're trying to assign a value to an object which is not an lvalue. You can still do something like *(ptr+10) = "Blue"; but this will not do what you want

Comment: @ShubhamSingla I edited my answer, saying the same as some other guys including Gojita above

Comment: "is not a lvalue but a value" -> " is not a lvalue but a rvalue" ?

Comment: @user463035818 no, if I am not wrong a _rvalue_ (renamed _prvalue_)  can be assigned (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: but "value" is just the most general term that does not imply that you cannot assign to it, no?

Comment: @user463035818 in my personal a value cannot. What is the right name for you ?

Comment: dont know, thats why I asked, my standardese is rather crappy, I always try to break things down to something simple that i can understand, which in this case is just "this wont work" but that doesnt qualify as an answer